# Do Java versions 9 or above have disableable JComboBox items?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, disable

Long story short, I'm coming back to Java after a while away. I need to stay with JDK 8 for an initial period for technical reasons although I'm intending to move to whatever is the then-latest in the next few months. In the meantime I need a `JComboBox`  whose items can be disabled. What I mean by this is they're painted in grey, and not able to be selected by the user.

I see this issue has been dealt with many times here over the years, and all the solutions seem, on admittedly quick examination, to have drawbacks. So I'm wondering, with fingers crossed, whether `JComboBox` in its more recent incarnations has solved the problem. Strikes me as a reasonable thing to hope for, since it's a little pointless having a method `setEnabled(boolean)` whose effect, both visually and functionally, is nil!

Can someone please confirm whether newer versions of Java have solved this problem?

Comment: 1) Don't miss the chance to add the Java & Swing tags! They have oodles more followers than either the `JComboBox` or 'disable' tags. I only found this by accident (& added both tags). 2) *"I see this issue has been dealt with many times here over the years"* Care to link to those posts, so we can see what they are doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for adding the extra tags, I appreciate the exposure to a wider audience.  I didn't list the posts because they all describe roll-your-own solutions and I'm not interested in those.  My question describes all and exactly what I'm interested in here :)